# How to start X without logging in console?

Tags: command-line, xorg, lightdm, desktop-environments

My filesystem is based on Ubuntu server and I installed xorg and openbox on it.

I've made it auto-login and auto startx, but when boot and shutdown, I can always see the

```
root@arm:#
```

or something like that on the top-left corner of the screen. I want to hide it.

I know that Ubuntu Desktop use lightdm as a service and start X without logging into terminal, say, `tty1`, can I make it myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a boot splash, there are a few to choose from, but Ubuntu usually uses plymouth.  Installing plymoth should be enough to accomplish what you asked.

```
sudo aptitude install plymouth
```

If you need more control, you can follow this tutorial

http://handytutorial.com/change-the-boot-splash-screen-theme-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/

Comment: Plymouth is running on my x86 box but it seems that it's not enough to accomplish what I asked.
I do get boot and shutdown splash, but after the boot splash and after the shutdown splash, the terminal appears for one or several seconds before X starts or poweroff. I've tried many times but still failed to fix it. I've changed the PAM and issue to have less verbose only to make it better, but still can't solve it.

Comment: WOW! I just tried to startx in rc.local instead of in .profile, seems that solve almost all my problems! I'll go on with it.

Comment: I got splash and solves all the problems, thanks!